# Tarantool multipart bitset index

Tags: indexing, bitset, tarantool

```
box.space.test:create_index('secondary', {type='BITSET', unique=false, parts={2,'num', 3,'num'}})
---
- error: 'Can''t create or modify index ''secondary'' in space ''test'': BITSET index key can not be multipart
```

Tarantool 1.6.7-591-g7d4dbbb

I have table with structure:

```
id,
param1: {1,50,70} #values[1-256]
param2: {6,8,128} #values[1-128]
```

And need to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE param1 HAVE {1,2} AND param2 HAVE {78}
```

So I can do it creating 256 bit + 128 bit BITSET index. How I can make it?

Comment: You can try tarantool 1.8 it has SQL support. It can be downloaded from https://tarantool.org/download.html.

Comment: If it make full scan for such query - it is not good solution... It will be full scan?